Problems with headers and simple navbar
HTML code:
login.php :
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 170px; margin-bottom: 150px">
   <header><?php require('header.php'); ?></header>
   <?php require('navbar-login.php'); ?>
   <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
      require('process-login.php'); } ?>
...


PHP code:
navbar-login.php :
<div class="row fixed-top py-2" style="margin-top: 86px; background-color: #c0c0c0">
   <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-8"></div>
   <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-4">
      <nav>
         <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="location.href = 'index.php'"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="location.href = 'form-register.php'"><i class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i></button>
     </div>
      </nav>
   </div>
</div>


process-login.php :
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
   try {
      $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
      if  ((empty($email)) || (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) {
         $errors[] = '<strong>No email</strong>: check.';
      }
      $password = filter_var( $_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
      if (empty($password)) {
         $errors[] = '<strong>No password</strong>: check.';
      }
      if (empty($errors)) {  
         require ('mysqli_connect.php');
     $query = "SELECT user_id, name, surname, password FROM table WHERE email=?";
     $q = mysqli_stmt_init($dbcon);
     mysqli_stmt_prepare($q, $query);
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, "s", $email); 
     mysqli_stmt_execute($q);
     $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($q);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
           session_start();
           $_SESSION['user_id'] = (int) $row['user_id'];
           $_SESSION['name'] = (string) $row['name'];
           $_SESSION['surname'] = (string) $row['surname'];
           mysqli_stmt_free_result($q);
           $dbcon->close();
           header('Location: dashboard.php');
           exit();
        }
    else {...
...

If I comment the line <?php require('navbar-login.php'); ?> in the HTML login.php file, it's ok. Else I get the warning: PHP Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent.
I know that no code can be before session_start() and that the problem is the navbar, but I need the navbar to navigate!
I used the same code explained in "Practical PHP 7, MySQL 8, and MariaDB Website Databases" by Adrian W. West & Steve Prettyman.
Where did I go wrong?

Move your process-login.php further up. From what you have there, there's absolutely no reason why it needs to be in the middle of the output. I'm surprised you're getting that message only with the navbar file, since there should be no output at all before the session is started, not even the body tags in login.php
